# Ajax uploading dom gets slower until chrome crashes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page loaded in via Ajax (long story but I need multiple pages in a single html file for javascript enabled browsers and for them not to be loaded if js disabled). The pages loaded via Ajax also have additional ajax links. So the page gets loaded in and if you click links within that page it loads content and updates the dom. This all works fine but if you keep clicking the Ajax links to update the content the page gets slower and slower until the browser crashes so I'm guessing it has to be a memory link (particularly bad in Chrome but this may be because its a bit more of a resource hog than Firefox).

I'm wondering whether it could be because within the ajax callback I'm calling the function again - I'm doing this otherwise the links within the ajax content won't have the ajax event applied to them (even though I thought .on was supposed to do this in a similar way to .live did). Anyway I'm thinking the below may be obvious to someone, any help very much appreciated.

```
function ajaxContent() {
    $('.ajaxContentWrapper').on('click', 'a.ajaxContentTrigger', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var myUrl = $(this).attr("href") + " .ajaxContent";
        $(".ajaxContentWrapper").load(myUrl,function(){
            ajaxContent();  
        });

    return false;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the ajax calls in chrome developer tools?
Also i don`t understand the function you provide, what is wrong with this approach?:

```
$('.ajaxContentWrapper').on('click', 'a.ajaxContentTrigger', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myUrl = $(this).attr("href") + " .ajaxContent";
    $(".ajaxContentWrapper").load(myUrl);
});
```

Comment: I have tried looking at the ajax calls. They work fine but the response times get longer and longer. The function I provided offers a callback once the ajax has loaded which then triggers some additional plugins which are applied to the loaded content. For simplicity I didn't add in the additional plugins but they came before the .on click (that's why on the callback I reference the main function to reload these plugins) - does that make sense?

Comment: I think everytime you call ajaxContent a new `click` handler is added to the element, so after some clicks there might be just as much handlers that are calling the ajax. Thus it`s getting slower and slower. Besides it`s not utilising jQuery`s in-time event handling.

Comment: you beat me to it. I went back and double checked in chrome tools and this time the ajax calls were actually the same. It was the click handlers slowing it down. So instead of referencing the main function I just load in the specific plugins in the callback and all is working fine...although I'm sure that when I did this before the ajax links weren't loading in the ajax content...but hey ho all works now. Thanks for your suggestions and getting me to recheck the Ajax in chrome tools :)